# Exception reason/message. Am I reinventing the wheel here?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want some kind of mechanism to have more information about a caught exception. (Specifically exceptions I throw myself to abort transactions) I've looked around and pretty much the only thing I could find was "Use the info log". This to me does not seem like a good idea. For one it is cumbersome to access and find the last message. And it is limited in size so at some point the new messages won't even show up.

So my idea is the following: Create a class NuException and <strike>pass an instance of that through all methods</strike> store an instance in the class where the work methods are located. When I need to throw an exception I call a method on it similar to `Global::error()` but this one takes an identifier and a message.

Once I reach my catch block I can access those from <strike>my object</strike> the class that contains the work methods similarly to how CLRExceptions work.

```
class NuException
{
  "public" str identifier;
  "public" str message;

  public Exception error(str _id, str _msg)
  {
    //set fields
    return Exception::Error;
  }
}

class Worker
{
  "public" NuException exception;

  void foo()
  {
    throw this.exception.error("Foo", "Record Foo already exists");
  }

  void bar()
  {
    this.foo();
  }
}

void Job()
{
  Worker w = new Worker();
  try
  {
    w.bar(ex);
  }
  catch (Exception::Error)
  {
    info(w.exception().message());
  }
}
```

It works but isn't there a better way? Surely someone must have come up with a solution to work around this shortcoming in AX?

Comment: Although for [tag:dynamics-365-operations], [Catching exceptions in AX 7](http://dev.goshoom.net/en/2017/06/catching-exceptions-in-ax-7/) might be an interesting read for you.

Comment: @FH-Inway Thanks. That's great information. IF you have AX7. It doesn't really add anything that's usable in AX 2012...

Comment: Unrestricted `catch` is a no-go, avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

While your "brilliant" scheme "works", it gets boring pretty fast, as you now must transport your `NuException` object deep down 20 level from the listener (`job`) to the thrower (`foo`). Your `bar` method and other middle men has no interest or knowledge about your exception scheme but must pass it on anyway.
**This is no longer the case after the update.**

There are several ways to go.

1. Use an [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) like the [Event broker](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Event_broker) or in AX 2012 and newer use [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg839762.aspx).
2. Stick to the `infolog` system and you use an [InfoAction](http://kashperuk.blogspot.dk/2008/09/sysinfoaction-class-description-improve.html) class to peggy bag your information to be used later. It can be used to display a stack trace or other interesting information.
3. Use a dedicated table for logging.

The third way may seem impractical, as any errors will undo the insert in the log. This is the default behavior but can be circumvented.

```
MyLogTable log;
Connection con = new UserConnection();
con.ttsBegin();
log.setConnection(con);
... // Set your fields
log.insert();
con.ttsCommit();
```

Your way to go depends on circumstances you do not mention.

Comment: Again. InfoLog doesn't seem like a viable option. I've easily got hundreds of thousands of entries in this scenario and it gets cut off after 1000. I hadn't thought of the event and delegate system, though. I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: In that case you should persue you own logging (to a table), scrolling 100000 lines would be no good either. You can use `infolog.errorsPerBatch` to avoid overwhelming the user. See https://axblog4u.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/what-is-the-%E2%80%9Cmessage-limit-of-infolog%E2%80%9D-in-dynamics-ax/

Comment: I've thought about using delegates and events but this would mean I'd have to wire up some kind of handler to receive the message and then fetch the response from my main catch block. Then I realized I could store my "exception" in the class that does the work (see edit). If you could maybe critique I'd be very grateful. It feels sufficiently convenient for now but I'll look into the idea of a logging table too. If you cold add that to your answer I'm probably ready to accept it.

Comment: Looks better, as the class handles its own exception without any middle men. But again you probably should not swallow the error without saying. Also the catch may fail to find any message, if the throw was not through NuException.